# I'm having trouble running my Flutter app in release mode - android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, flutter, dart

1. I'm having trouble at running my Flutter app in release mode.  I tried to  build with apk and with the bundletool and i got the same error "unfortunately, Hanoti has stopped"
2. in the debug mode is running normally.
3. this is the image:
   [the image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAcs6.png)
4. in debug mode:
   [the image in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtIFb.png)
5. my app files: like

   - android\build.gradle:
   - android\app\build.gradle:
   - androidManifest.xml:
   - main.dart:
     ... etc.

6. i did all that, and the logs after i run:

   - flutter clean
   - gradlew cleanBuildCache

**Target Platform:** Android
**Target OS version/browser:** minSdkVersion 21 (android 5.0), targetSdkVersion 28 (android 9)
**Devices:** galaxy_nexus_api_23:5554 => emulator
**My Develpment machine.**:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          N/A
Registered Organization:   N/A
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~2701 Mhz
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Total Physical Memory:     8,092 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,497 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  13,468 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 7,171 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    6,297 MB
```

## Logs

### flutter run --verbose

https://gist.github.com/AttalliAyoub/c4572d6f80f616b3229789f2ddf32b6a#file-flutter-run-verbose

### flutter build apk --split-per-abi --verbose

https://gist.github.com/AttalliAyoub/c4572d6f80f616b3229789f2ddf32b6a#file-flutter-build-apk-split-per-abi-verbose

### flutter analyze

```
Analyzing hanoti...

   info - Unused import: 'package:hanoti/services/interfaces.dart' - lib\main.dart:9:8 - unused_import
   info - This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or
          more of its instance fields are not final: UserIcon._radius, UserIcon._border -
          lib\pages\chat.dart:155:7 - must_be_immutable
   info - The left operand uses '?.', so its value can be null - lib\pages\chat.dart:228:7 -
          null_aware_before_operator
   info - The value of the '?.' operator can be 'null', which isn't appropriate in a condition -
          lib\pages\chat.dart:288:26 - null_aware_in_condition
   info - This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or
          more of its instance fields are not final: PickChat._chatService - lib\pages\pickChat.dart:14:7
          - must_be_immutable
   info - Unused import: 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart' -
          lib\pages\pickStore.dart:2:8 - unused_import
   info - The left operand uses '?.', so its value can be null - lib\pages\pickStore.dart:71:27 -
          null_aware_before_operator
   info - The left operand uses '?.', so its value can be null - lib\pages\products.dart:38:11 -
          null_aware_before_operator
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\pages\searchForStore.dart:32:27 - close_sinks
   info - The value of the local variable '_current' isn't used - lib\pages\showproduct.dart:21:9 -
          unused_local_variable
   info - Dead code - lib\pages\showproduct.dart:78:31 - dead_code
   info - Use `;` instead of `{}` for empty constructor bodies - lib\pages\storeInfo.dart:6:25 -
          empty_constructor_bodies
   info - Prefer using /// for doc comments - lib\pages\videoCall.dart:5:1 - slash_for_doc_comments
   info - Unused import: 'package:hanoti/services/resp.dart' - lib\pages\workspace.dart:9:8 -
          unused_import
   info - The value of the field '_profile' isn't used - lib\pages\workspace.dart:22:8 - unused_field
   info - The left operand uses '?.', so its value can be null - lib\pages\workspace.dart:59:11 -
          null_aware_before_operator
   info - The left operand uses '?.', so its value can be null - lib\pages\workspace.dart:257:7 -
          null_aware_before_operator
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\services\auth.dart:27:25 - close_sinks
   info - 'enablePersistence' is deprecated and shouldn't be used - lib\services\auth.dart:31:14 -
          deprecated_member_use
   info - 'enablePersistence' is deprecated and shouldn't be used - lib\services\chat.dart:10:14 -
          deprecated_member_use
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:22:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:23:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:24:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:25:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:26:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:62:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:65:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase - lib\services\interfaces.dart:66:10 -
          non_constant_identifier_names
   info - 'enablePersistence' is deprecated and shouldn't be used - lib\services\products.dart:46:14 -
          deprecated_member_use
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\services\resp.dart:8:25 - close_sinks
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\services\resp.dart:9:27 - close_sinks
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\services\store.dart:12:26 - close_sinks
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\services\store.dart:13:31 - close_sinks
   info - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink` - lib\services\store.dart:15:32 - close_sinks
   info - 'enablePersistence' is deprecated and shouldn't be used - lib\services\store.dart:21:14 -
          deprecated_member_use
   info - The value of the '?.' operator can be 'null', which isn't appropriate as an operand of a
          logical operator - lib\services\store.dart:128:28 - null_aware_in_logical_operator
   info - This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or
          more of its instance fields are not final: SearchAppBar.actions - lib\shared\searchBar.dart:5:7
          - must_be_immutable

37 issues found. (ran in 66.5s)
```

### flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.15-pre.39, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.504], locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.10.15-pre.39 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 2adda80c10 (5 days ago), 2019-10-09 16:58:41 -0700
    • Engine revision e693192167
    • Dart version 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.6.0 41d13f0ffe)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\android-sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\android-sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.1.2)
    • Visual Studio at E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.1.29001.49

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 38.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3
    • Flutter plugin version 40.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 192.6817.14

[√] VS Code (version 1.39.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\snake\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM G355H • 4203e926b406c100 • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
    • Windows  • Windows          • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.504]

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 8):

You should try to install the app using **flutter run --release**.
In this way, you will see what kind of error the app throws during the crash.

Also, you cand find more info [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes#release) if you haven't already checked the page.

Answer (score 7):

you could run your app in `--profile` mode and get `--release` like performance and get the logs like in the `--debug` mode.

you could find the Uncaught Exception then.

provide the logs if needed more help finding the issue.

:hearts

Comment: You saviour, how could I not know about it