# apk not installing if install then showing blank screen.Flutter dart language

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, flutter-debug

I am working on the Dart language.I generate split-per-abi (.apk) as well as release (.apk).After that when I try to install it did not install on some devices or in which this apk installs it's did not showing any content on a white blank screen.

Flutter 2.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 60bd88df91 (6 weeks ago) • 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
Engine • revision 40441def69
Tools • Dart 2.12.0

min-sdk-version 23

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<application
    android:label="Share card"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Comment: maybe some of your devices' sdk is lower than 23. It said `min-sdk-version 23`

Comment: it's min-sdk-version 23  now it's  installing but not showing any content only white or black screen showing not working

Comment: check the error logs made by the app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381039/im-having-trouble-running-my-flutter-app-in-release-mode-android